# Unable to debug some asp.net core2.2 web pages with Firefox. How can I debug with Firefox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, firefox

Background

- asp.net core 2.2
- Browser: Firefox Edition : 71.0(64 bit)
- Code editor: VS profession 2019
- [Source code](https://github.com/jianba/ASP.NET-Core-MVC-with-EF-Core---tutorial-series)

Detial

1. During this time, I tried to debug my pages with Firefox, but I couldn't debug some of them. That's it.

   [image]

   This is to use other browsers (chrome kernel) debugging, we can get index page.

[image]

Doubt

- How can I debug with Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only debug javascript on the browser. You can debug your asp.net core c# code with visual studio, basically your IDE not just Visual Studio.
[image]

Below i am using a page with inline javascript inside HTML. Same happens with no js in page.

> We cannot see the index page inside firefox's developer tools.

All screenhots were taken with the same app(just a new MVC app). I am using **Firefox 70.0.1(64 bit)**

[image]

Comment: What if there is some inline javascript in the HTML?

Comment: First of all. You should not use inline javascript unless you absolutely have to. There are truthfully cases that you have to. Still Firefox will not set a breakpoint. Or even find your page. Try a simple example.